# How to Dynamically Compute Value in View and Display in Template (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

I want to dynamically pull values from two user input fields, a textbox and a dropdown, and then send those values to my view to calculate a new value and display said value in my template. With my current solution, `{{ total }}` never produces a value when the user inputs `hours` and an `engineer_level` is selected. This seems like a fairly simple scenario, but I am new to Django/Python. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Additionally, how might I store a value as a session variable?

views.py

```
def presales(request):
    my_opportunities = cwObj.get_opportunities()
    context = {'my_opportunities': my_opportunities}
    return render(request, 'website/presales.html', context)

def presales_total(request):
    hours = request.GET.get('hours')
    engineer_level = request.GET.get('selected_engineer_level')
    if engineer_level == 'PM':
        wage = 225
    elif engineer_level == 'Solutions Technician':
        wage = 175
    elif engineer_level == 'Solutions Engineer':
        wage = 225
    elif engineer_level == 'Senior Solutions Engineer':
        wage = 275
    elif engineer_level == 'Solutions Architect':
        wage = 275
    total = wage * hours

    context = {'total': total}
    return render(request, 'website/presales_total.html', context)
```

presales.html

```
<div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input class="input" name="hours" id="hours" placeholder="Hours">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="label">Engineer Level:</label>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="select">
                            <select name="selected_engineer_level" id="selected_engineer_level">
                                <option value="">Engineer Level</option>
                                <option value="PM">PM</option>
                                <option value="Solutions Technician">Solutions Technician</option>
                                <option value="Solutions Engineer">Solutions Engineer</option>
                                <option value="Senior Solutions Engineer">Senior Solutions Engineer</option>
                                <option value="Solutions Architect">Solutions Architect</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-info" type="button">Add Task</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="label is-medium is-pulled-right">Total: {{ total }}</span>
```

presales_total.html

```
Total:
<span>{{ total }}</span>
```

Comment: What's your question? What happens when you try this?

Comment: Currently nothing happens, `{{ total }}` never produces a value.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is it proper practice to have different views handling the data on a single template? Like how I send the data I want in this scenario to `presales_total.html` to dispaly it on `presales.html`. Or should I handle all in multiple views but use a singular template. Thanks!

Comment: Not only is it not "proper practice", but it doesn't work at all. A URL maps to a single view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how can I handle the user input fields in my logic without getting an UnboundLocalError since the values are not defined until some user input? My views are mapped to seperate URLs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman in order to dynamically handle the user input fields, should I use Ajax or is there an easier way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is happening when you press submit because you haven't wrapped your inputs in a

```
<form action=".../presales_total" method="post">
...
</form>
```

tag.

You will need to include a csrf token `{% csrf_token %}`, convert your button type to 'submit', as well as changing your method to POST.

Finally, make sure you convert the hours input with `int()` so that you are not multiplying a string.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect  ## Added 'redirect'

def presales(request):
    # my_opportunities = cwObj.get_opportunities()
    # context = {'my_opportunities': my_opportunities}
    return render(request, 'sales/presales.html')

def presales_total(request):
    if request.method=='POST':  # add this line

        hours = request.POST['hours']   # change to POST
        engineer_level = request.POST['selected_engineer_level']   # change to post
        if engineer_level == 'PM':
            wage = 225
        elif engineer_level == 'Solutions Technician':
            wage = 175
        elif engineer_level == 'Solutions Engineer':
            wage = 225
        elif engineer_level == 'Senior Solutions Engineer':
            wage = 275
        elif engineer_level == 'Solutions Architect':
            wage = 275
        total = wage * int(hours)   # POST request default submissions to string, convert to type int with int()

        request.session['total'] = total ## store the value in session
        return redirect('/sales/presales') ## send the user back to the first page
```

presales.html

```
<form action="/sales/presales_total" method="post">   # add this line
    {% csrf_token %}   # add this line
<div class="field">
    <div class="control">
        <input class="input" name="hours" id="hours" placeholder="Hours">
    </div>
</div>
<label class="label">Engineer Level:</label>
<div class="field">
    <div class="select">
        <select name="selected_engineer_level" id="selected_engineer_level">
            <option value="">Engineer Level</option>
            <option value="PM">PM</option>
            <option value="Solutions Technician">Solutions Technician</option>
            <option value="Solutions Engineer">Solutions Engineer</option>
            <option value="Senior Solutions Engineer">Senior Solutions Engineer</option>
            <option value="Solutions Architect">Solutions Architect</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
<div class="control">
    <button class="button is-info" type="submit">Add Task</button>   # change to 'submit'
</div>
</div>
<span class="label is-medium is-pulled-right">Total: {{ request.session.total }}</span>
</form>   # add this line ## change the template variable to 'request.session.total
```

Based on your comment, you can also `return redirect("sales/presales") to display the value on the same form. You'll have to store the computed total in a session variable to be able to re-access it. If you edit the question to include that I can provide an example.

Edit: To include displaying the total on first template.

In order to make use of sessions we need to run `python manage.py migrate` from the command line at the base level of your project folder to initialize the database to store the session information and pass information between views. Once you've done that, you can import the `redirect` function to

- calculate the total
- store it in the session variable 'total'
- send the user back to the presales page

There we can access the session variable with {{ request.session.total }}.

It's not the fanciest solution, but it works.

Comment: thank you for the response, I updated the original post like you asked. Originally, my idea was to have the total be dynamically calculated when the user inputed the necessary values. Is this possible without Ajax? Or should I just use a form action for on submit?

Comment: It's definitely possible to calculate values dynamically with Javascript. However, if you just want to use standard Django, you pass the POST request to a second view which does your calculation and then returns the user to the first page. I've edited my response to include a method of accomplishing that.

Comment: ok great, thank you. My only concern is that I have other data being submitted by the form, so can I pass the POST request to the second view while maintaining the data in other fields? Additionally, at the end of the workflow, I need to POST all of the data in the form.

Comment: You can store the data from the form in a dictionary and pass it to the session. Then you can repopulate the form when it reloads with those values when the page renders. If you're just deploying this site for a small user base that will work fine. For a production website capable of scaling to large numbers, you'll probably want to look into AJAX as you mentioned before. If this is working, would you mind marking the the question answered?